# How to order by firebase storage list

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

Can not find any function in firebase storage to list all files in a specific order like ascending or descending, i have tried listoptions but it supports only two arguments **maxResults** and **pageToken**

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud Storage List API does not have the ability to sort anything by some criteria you choose.  If you need the ability to query objects in a bucket, you should consider also storing information about your objects in a database that can be queried with the flexibility that you require.  You will need to keep that database up to date as the contents of your bucket change (perhaps using Cloud Functions triggers).  This is a common thing to implement, since Cloud Storage is optimized only for storage huge amounts of data for fast retrieval at extremely low costs - it is *not* also trying to be a database for object metadata.

Please also see:

- [gsutil / gcloud storage file listing sorted date descending?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045725/gsutil-gcloud-storage-file-listing-sorted-date-descending)