# How to Sort Files in Firebase Storage by Last Modified

Tags: list, firebase, sorting, storage, last-modified

When uploading files directly into the Firebase Storage dashboard, the files are automatically sorted by Name. Is there a way to order them by Last Modified Date?

Sometimes, I'm able to hover the mouse over the "Last Modified" "Type" and "Name" and "Size" and an arrow appears next to each that allows me to then sort/order the list of files by which ever arrow is selected. But after many attempts, I can't find a way to automatically sort the files in this way. I have no idea what prompts the arrows to appear, they just do randomly. Sometimes they don't appear at all.

Please help if possible.

[image]

Hovering mouse over the headers. I'm expecting an arrow to appear to allow me to sort the files by "Last Modified"

Answer (score 1):

One thing that worked for me is scrolling all the way down the bottom of the list to the end. And after, when I come back up to the top headers, the arrow appears.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorting is not available for Firebase Storage. Please see the answer to this other, similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70918526/13096296

That being said, if you keep scrolling down in your Firebase Storage dashboard until all the files are displayed in the browser, eventually you'll see those arrows that you mentioned in the headers. I'm assuming this is an in-browser (client) sorting that becomes available once all the rows of data are displayed.

Scrolling down to display all the files may not be feasible, depending on how many files you've got in Storage.