# How to download files within a certain date range using gsutil?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have a gcs bucket with thousands of files and I want to download only those files which fall within certain date. Even downloading all files created 'after' a certain date will be sufficient.

Comment: I would suggest to develop a bash script - the first step - using gsutil - get the list of files; the second step to process them (using gsutil)...

Comment: gsutil does not support filtering by date.

Comment: You can try checking this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44032156/16531380). To add, you can also check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to save the files in a date bucket.

or save metadata about your files in a database.

Until you do that.
If you are a linux command line guy.

1. list the files with grep.

> ```
> gsutil ls -l gs://YOUR_BUCKET|grep 2023-07-04T > outfile
> ```

outfile is now filled with gs://file_name phats.
You can use any script language to loop over lines in outfile and download the files.

2. BONUS: Create a download script file.

> ```
> gsutil ls -l gs://YOUR_BUCKET|grep 2023-07-04T|awk '{print (NR>1 ? "gsutil cp " : "") $3 " .";}' > outfile.sh
> ```

outfile.sh is should be filled with `gsutil cp gs://files_path .`
Now you can run the script.

> ```
> bash outfile.sh
> ```

3. BONUS II: Add file by size filter. files bigger then 1 MB, for example.

> ```
> gsutil ls -l gs://prod-prober-job-screenshot-results|grep 2023-07-04T |awk '$1 > 1000000  {print (NR>1 ? "gsutil cp " : "") $3 " .";}' > filescp.sh
> ```

> ```
> bash outfile.sh
> ```