# GOOGLE STORAGE - how can i know if my bucket was uploaded a new file

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

i'm working for the first time with google storage with no experience on it

I have a question that does google storage have an feature that if storage got a new uploaded file, storage will send a notification to client that have subscribed
Or rise an event that can be watched from another place.

My solution is list all object from bucket and save it to a temp file. After that, I list object again every minute then if a new file had been uploaded, it would not be in a temp file so i can know it. But i think this way is not such good if the thing above exists.

Many thanks.

Comment: very similar question asked here and perfectly answered
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074834/how-do-i-get-notified-when-an-object-is-uploaded-to-my-gcs-bucket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Object Change Notification](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification) can be used to notify an application
  when an object is updated or added to a bucket.
- Alternatively, you can use [Cloud Pub/Sub Notifications for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications), which are actually the recommended way to track changes to objects in your Cloud Storage buckets because they're faster, more flexible, easier to set up, and more cost-effective.
- Ultimately, if you only want to trigger a lightweight, stand-alone function in response to events and don't want to manage a Cloud Pub/Sub topic, use Cloud Functions with [Storage Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) which can respond to change notifications emerging from Google Cloud Storage. These notifications can be configured to trigger in response to various events inside a bucket—object creation, deletion, archiving and metadata updates.