# Specifying Metadata to publish with Google Cloud Storage Notifications

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub, gsutil

I have gotten started with the help of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074834/how-do-i-get-notified-when-an-object-is-uploaded-to-my-gcs-bucket), giving me a gsutil command:

```
gsutil notification create \
-t bucketcfpubsub -f json \
-e OBJECT_FINALIZE gs://bucketcfpubsub
```

With which I got this message published:

```
b'{\n "kind": "storage#object",\n "id": "bucketcfpubsub/test.txt/1544681756538155",\n "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucketcfpubsub/o/test.txt",\n "name": "test.txt",\n "bucket": "bucketcfpubsub",\n "generation": "1544681756538155",\n "metageneration": "1",\n "contentType": "text/plain",\n "timeCreated": "2018-12-13T06:15:56.537Z",\n "updated": "2018-12-13T06:15:56.537Z",\n "storageClass": "STANDARD",\n "timeStorageClassUpdated": "2018-12-13T06:15:56.537Z",\n "size": "1938",\n "md5Hash": "sDSXIvkR/PBg4mHyIUIvww==",\n "mediaLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/bucketcfpubsub/o/test.txt?generation=1544681756538155&alt=media",\n "crc32c": "UDhyzw==",\n "etag": "CKvqjvuTnN8CEAE="\n}\n'
```

You can see it more 'readably' [here](https://bucketcfpubsub.appspot.com/)

However, [this documentation guide](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications#notification-configs) hints that we could trim that down to specific metadata that we're interested in. For example, the name of the file, with "objectId". But it doesn't exactly say how this can be implemented through gsutil. In the above wall of text, there is also "timeCreated" and "size".

I would like to set up a notification that outputs the name of the file uploaded as the MESSAGE, and timeCreated and size as attributes.

Could anyone please explain how the input code can be manipulated to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to change the payload to only include a subset of fields. The notification payloads always include the full object metadata if you specify `JSON_API_V1` for the `payloadFormat`.

The only alternative is to set `payloadFormat` to `NONE`. This will send no payload at all, but you can still extra some info from the [attributes](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications#attributes) of the notification. For your use case, the attributes contain `objectId`, but not `size` and `timeCreated`. For those additional fields, you'll need to read the full payload.

To specify no payload with gsutil, use the `-f none` option. See for details:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/notification#options