# How do I write a Cloud Function to receive, parse, and publish PubSub messages?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-python

This can be considered a follow-up to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074834/how-do-i-get-notified-when-an-object-is-uploaded-to-my-gcs-bucket), but I need more help with moving things along. Hopefully someone can have a look over my attempts below and provide further guidance.

To summarize, I need a cloud function that

1. Is triggered by a PubSub message being published in topic **A** (this can be done in UI).
2. reads a messy object change notification message in "push" PubSub topic **A**.
3. "parse" it
4. publish a message in PubSub topic **B**, with the original message ID as data, and other metadata (e.g. file name, size, time) as attributes.

. 1:

Example of a messy object change notification:

> \n "kind": "storage#object",\n "id": "bucketcfpubsub/test.txt/1544681756538155",\n "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucketcfpubsub/o/test.txt",\n "name": "test.txt",\n "bucket": "bucketcfpubsub",\n "generation": "1544681756538155",\n "metageneration": "1",\n "contentType": "text/plain",\n "timeCreated": "2018-12-13T06:15:56.537Z",\n "updated": "2018-12-13T06:15:56.537Z",\n "storageClass": "STANDARD",\n "timeStorageClassUpdated": "2018-12-13T06:15:56.537Z",\n "size": "1938",\n "md5Hash": "sDSXIvkR/PBg4mHyIUIvww==",\n "mediaLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/bucketcfpubsub/o/test.txt?generation=1544681756538155&alt=media",\n "crc32c": "UDhyzw==",\n "etag": "CKvqjvuTnN8CEAE="\n}\n

To clarify, is this a message with blank "data" field, and all the information above are in attribute pairs (like "attribute name": "attribute data")? Or is it just a long string stuffed into the "data" field, with no "attributes"?

. 2:

In the above thread, a "pull" subscription is used. Is it better than using a "push" subscription? Push sample below:

```
def create_push_subscription(project_id,
                             topic_name,
                             subscription_name,
                             endpoint):
    """Create a new push subscription on the given topic."""
    # [START pubsub_create_push_subscription]
    from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

    # TODO project_id = "Your Google Cloud Project ID"
    # TODO topic_name = "Your Pub/Sub topic name"
    # TODO subscription_name = "Your Pub/Sub subscription name"
    # TODO endpoint = "https://my-test-project.appspot.com/push"

    subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
    topic_path = subscriber.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)
    subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(
        project_id, subscription_name)

    push_config = pubsub_v1.types.PushConfig(
        push_endpoint=endpoint)

    subscription = subscriber.create_subscription(
        subscription_path, topic_path, push_config)

    print('Push subscription created: {}'.format(subscription))
    print('Endpoint for subscription is: {}'.format(endpoint))
    # [END pubsub_create_push_subscription]
```

Or do I need further code after this to receive messages?

**Also, doesn't this create a new subscriber every time the Cloud Function is triggered by a pubsub message being published? Should I add a subscription delete code at the end of the CF, or are there more efficient ways to do this?**

. 3:

Next, to parse the code, this sample code doing a few attributes as follows:

```
def summarize(message):
    # [START parse_message]
    data = message.data
    attributes = message.attributes

    event_type = attributes['eventType']
    bucket_id = attributes['bucketId']
    object_id = attributes['objectId']
```

Will this work with my above notification in 1:?

. 4:

How do I separate the topic_name? Steps 1 and 2 use topic **A**, while this step is to publish into topic **B**. Is is as simple as re-writing the topic_name in the below code example?

```
# TODO topic_name = "Your Pub/Sub topic name"

publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)

for n in range(1, 10):
    data = u'Message number {}'.format(n)
    # Data must be a bytestring
    data = data.encode('utf-8')
    # Add two attributes, origin and username, to the message
    publisher.publish(
        topic_path, data, origin='python-sample', username='gcp')

print('Published messages with custom attributes.')
```

Source where I got most of the sample code from (besides the above thread):[python-docs-samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/pubsub/cloud-client/subscriber.py). Will adapting and stringing the above code samples together produce useful code? Or will I still be missing stuff like "import ****"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not attempt to manually create a Subscriber running in Cloud Functions.  Instead, follow the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub) for setting up a Cloud Function which will be called with all messages sent to a given topic by passing the `--trigger-topic` command line parameter.

To address some of your other concerns:

“Should I add a subscription delete code at the end of the CF”- Subscriptions are long-lived resources corresponding to a specific backlog of messages.  If the subscription is created and deleted at the end of the cloud function, messages sent when it does not exist will not be received.

“How do I separate the topic_name”- The ‘topic_name’ in this example refers to the last part of the string formatted like this `projects/project_id/topics/topic_name` that will appear on [this page](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/cloudpubsub/topicList) in the cloud console for your topic after it has been created.