# GCS Object Change Notifications for sub-folders

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

Following up to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074834/how-do-i-get-notified-when-an-object-is-uploaded-to-my-gcs-bucket) since I can't comment.

I've successfully created object change notifications as instructed by @Brandon Yarbrough (thanks!).

But I would like to narrow down the monitoring from the entire bucket to a sub-folder. For example, from 'gs://mainbucket/' to 'gs://mainbucket/subfolder1/'. However, attempting this in the same syntax returns this error.

> CommandException: notification create requires a GCS bucket name, but got 'gs://mainbucket/subfolder1/'

How should this function be implemented instead?

Comment: i followed the same thread  @Brandon Yarbrough, yet my script waiting saying Listening for messages on projects/bold-proton-236611/subscriptions/projects/bold-proton-236611/subscriptions/subtestbucketthhh any idea  or how can i checked my subscripbion , topic , is configured with my bucket

Comment: @syedirfan I'm not exactly sure what error you're getting, but these are common commands I use to check on pubsub `gcloud pubsub subscriptions list`, `notification list gs://$PROJECT` (use your own project_id), and `gcloud app services list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the sub-folder as a **prefix** of the objects that are uploaded in the bucket. You do that by adding `-p sub-folder`.

From the example in the other thread:

```
$ gsutil notification create \
    -t pubsup-topic-name -f json \
    -e OBJECT_FINALIZE \
    -p subfolder1/ gs://mainbucket
```

Comment: is there any way where i can check that my subscription & topic is configured with my bucket i followed the same thread yet unable to receive notification