# GCS Object Change Notification, pub/sub unable to receive any thing

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Following up to [quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074834/how-do-i-get-notified-when-an-object-is-uploaded-to-my-gcs-bucket/56947131#56947131)! since I can't comment.
I followed @Brandon Yarbrough instruction everything is configured the problem is I am not receiving anything script saying 
Listening for messages on `projects/[project_id]/subscriptions/projects/[project_id]/subscriptions/subtestbucketthhh`

Comment: @Brandon Yarbrough

Comment: Could you please verify the name of the topic your notifications are being published to? You can run `gsutil notification list [bucket_url]` to show the Cloud Pub/Sub topic name. Then verify that your subscription is attached to the topic by running `gcloud pubsub topics list-subscriptions [topic_name]`. It looks like you might be using an incorrect subscription name in your script: it should be in the format `projects/[project_id]/subscriptions/[subscription_name]`.

Comment: Yes , Topic_asr

Comment: Please check whether messages were published to your topic using the `pubsub.googleapis.com/topic/send_request_count` Stackdriver metric: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/monitoring If not, then something is misconfigured in between GCS and Pub/Sub.

Comment: If there are messages published, check the `pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/num_undelivered_messages` Stackdriver metric to make sure your subscription is able to access those messages. If there are no undelivered messages present, your subscription is not attached to the correct topic. If there are messages present, your client is probably not attached to the correct subscription or is not using the correct delivery type (pull or push delivery type).